# Different results from ExecuteNonQuery when deleting from database between query and stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a `SP_Delete` stored procedure allow to delete rows of data. When I create query statement in C#, I have two kinds of query:

- `Delete from table where id = @id`
- `exec SP_Delete @id`

I have this code:

```
int rowsAffected = 0;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connString); 

rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

return rowsAffected;
```

But, the `rowsAffected` returned:

- When I use query `Delete from table where id = @id` then `rowsAffected` = `number of record effected from table`. Ex: I delete 3 record then `rowsAffected` = `3`.
- When I use `exec SP_Delete @id` then `rowsAffected` always is `-1` although I delete more than 1 record. Ex: I delete 3 record then `rowsAffected` = `-1`

Could anyone explain the reason of the different between query and stored procedure?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/01/27/sqlcommand-executenonquery-returns-1-when-doing-insert-update-delete/

Comment: Most likely, you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in your stored procedure - that **prevents** the number of rows affected by the statement to be returned from the procedure. Remove that statement from your stored procedure, and you should get the actual number of rows affected by your command as a return value - just like with the inline query

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!